# Multiple utun[0-9] interfaces after using Migration Assistant to copy old macbook to new macbook

Tags: network, vpn, migration

I ran migration assistant with the source being a macbook I've had for 10 years and probably installed more than a couple VPNs on to a new M1 running `Monterey 12.6.8`.  Tunnelblick, Stanford VPN, openVPN, juniper, etc.

I would like to get rid of all of them.  And actually there's one that is still showing up in the menu bar even though I removed it from System Preferences->Networking

`ifconfig -a` show a lot of stuff

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=1203<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TXSTATUS,SW_TIMESTAMP>
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
anpi0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether aa:4d:86:8b:a9:f6 
    inet6 fe80::a84d:86ff:fe8b:a9f6%anpi0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: none
    status: inactive
anpi2: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether aa:4d:86:8b:a9:f8 
    inet6 fe80::a84d:86ff:fe8b:a9f8%anpi2 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x5 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: none
    status: inactive
anpi1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether aa:4d:86:8b:a9:f7 
    inet6 fe80::a84d:86ff:fe8b:a9f7%anpi1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x6 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: none
    status: inactive
ap1: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether be:d0:74:6b:eb:32 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
en4: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether aa:4d:86:8b:a9:d6 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: none
    status: inactive
en5: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether aa:4d:86:8b:a9:d7 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: none
    status: inactive
en6: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether aa:4d:86:8b:a9:d8 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: none
    status: inactive
en1: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 36:11:0b:9d:9b:80 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en2: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 36:11:0b:9d:9b:84 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=6463<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO,PARTIAL_CSUM,ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
    ether bc:d0:74:6b:eb:32 
    inet6 fe80::18c1:6207:f002:ccb6%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0xd 
    inet 192.168.0.71 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
en3: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 36:11:0b:9d:9b:88 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether d2:67:31:21:1f:98 
    inet6 fe80::d067:31ff:fe21:1f98%awdl0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xf 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 36:11:0b:9d:9b:80 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x0
    member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 11 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 12 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en3 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 14 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
llw0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether d2:67:31:21:1f:98 
    inet6 fe80::d067:31ff:fe21:1f98%llw0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x11 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1380
    inet6 fe80::aef2:7911:210d:7fd7%utun0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x12 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun1: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 2000
    inet6 fe80::1474:3f93:2e19:ed61%utun1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x13 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun2: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1000
    inet6 fe80::ce81:b1c:bd2c:69e%utun2 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x14 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun3: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1380
    inet6 fe80::2912:8fd8:b0ed:5b41%utun3 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x16 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun4: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1380
    inet6 fe80::666c:377d:861f:a746%utun4 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x19 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun5: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1380
    inet6 fe80::1f94:473a:b306:3826%utun5 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1a 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun6: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1380
    inet6 fe80::ae2f:d3fc:b445:a564%utun6 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1c 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun7: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1380
    inet6 fe80::def7:1b73:63a3:5114%utun7 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1d 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
ipsec0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
```

inspecting them doesn't yield much info

```
ifconfig -v utun7 
utun7: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1380 index 29
    eflags=1002080<TXSTART,NOAUTOIPV6LL,ECN_ENABLE>
    xflags=4<NOAUTONX>
    inet6 fe80::def7:1b73:63a3:5114%utun7 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1d 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    state availability: 0 (true)
    scheduler: FQ_CODEL 
    qosmarking enabled: no mode: none
    low power mode: disabled
    multi layer packet logging (mpklog): disabled
    routermode4: disabled
    routermode6: disabled
```

My question is how do I know which of these can be removed and how do I remove them?

Or would it be better to just re-OS the new laptop and manually transfer my files?   There's a lot of other junk I'm removing like 32-bit apps

edit:  not sure if this is helpful, but `sudo lsof | grep utun` yields a bunch of these

```
identitys   891                   me   19u    systm 0xfbafce9364bd7a63        0t0                     [ctl com.apple.net.utun_control id 4 unit 1]
```

pid 891 is `identityservicesd`

Comment: What *exact* macOS version is installed on this Mac?

Comment: @SteveChambers Monterey 12.6.8

Comment: sorry, missed the "exact" part